# I am ssh'ing to my server from cmd and running some scripts .I need to save the logs of that scripts into my local desktop folder

Tags: logging, ssh, cmd

i am ssh'ing to my server from cmd and running some scripts .I need to save the logs of that scripts into my local desktop folder . is there any way to do this .

from putty we can ssh and save those logs locally .is there any way to do the same in cmd?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MobaXterm instead of Putty to have a folder interface. Using MobaXterm you can even drag and drop files to your local desktop from remote, or to your remote from your desktop.

And a more precise answer and a better approach is to learn and use `scp` linux command. Here is a [manual](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php).

**Note:** If you are using an ssh key, you must define your ssh key at the beginning of the command:

`scp -i ~/.ssh/private_key`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass command or script name to ssh client and redirect output to local file.

```
# ssh user@example.com "ls" > ls_on_host.txt
```

Comment: but i will have to run multiple commands in the server to start my application,enterpassword etc and later i am going to run the script . This suggition would help for single command , please let me know how can i use this for multiple line commands